# Are the SSL Digital Security Certificates based on Kerberos Network Security Protocol

Tags: network, digital-signature, protocols, kerberos

I just want to know if digital certificates use the kerberos session key algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No they are very different in the most basic sense.  Kerberos uses tokens for authentication built using a symmetric cipher.  SSL allows you to pass secret data between two machines and uses asymmetric cryptography for authentication.  It is possible to use kerberos and ssl together,  but it is less common.